# Apple App store change its subtitle

Tags: ios, store

I what to change the my app subtitle in my app store listing.

Does anyone knows where I can do this? I've look all over the app version page and can't find the proper field

Comment: What subtitle are you talking about? There is no subtitle in the AppStore just you apps name.

Answer (score 1):

The Subtitle field is at App Information page (My App/App store/App Information).

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The Developer name can only be set once, on registering of your iTunes Connect account.